# Unexpected behavior of MapAt

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, map

For the description, I have a simplified problem like the following:

```
MapAt[f[1, #1], {a, b, c, d}, #2] & @@@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

will give

> ```
> {{a, f[1, 1][b], c, d}, {a, b, c, f[1, 3][d]}}
> ```

But actually `{a, f[1, 1][b], c, f[1, 3][d]}` is what I expected. What happened? How to adjust the code?

---

**Update:**

My real case is

```
bigList = Range @ 10;
veryBigList = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4, 10}};
Function[{binLevel, place}, 
         MapAt[BitSet[#, binLevel] &, bigList, place]] @@@ veryBigList
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 10}, {1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 26}}

In my case, the list size is very huge. If I use `Fold`, it will act on a very big result list every calculation, for the RAM so I want to avoid using `Fold`.

Comment: Would it help you if I rewrote your code as `{MapAt[f[1, 1], {a, b, c, d}, 2], MapAt[f[1, 3], {a, b, c, d}, 4]}`?

Comment: @J.M. Confusing still,as my degree of familiarity about this two functions,it won't give that result.

Comment: @Kuba 2 and 4 represent place.In you case,it should be `{a,f[1,2][f[1,1][b]],c,d}`

Comment: @march When the third parameter is number,you can omit the `{}`

Comment: I mean, using `@@@`, you are applying the `MapAt[ ... ]&` function to each element of the list, and so you generate a two element list, as you've found.

Comment: @march i was just about to write that myself :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Fold[
 Function[{data, spec}, MapAt[f[1, #1], data, #2] & @@ spec],
 {a, b, c, d},
 {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
 ]
```

> ```
> {a, f[1, 1][b], c, f[1, 3][d]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your method of `Fold`,but in my real case,I want to avoid it.Can we?

Comment: If use the `Fold`,In my case I should change it into `Fold[Function[{data,spec},Function[{binLevel,place},MapAt[BitSet[#,binLevel]&,data,place]]@@spec],bigList,veryBigList]`? It's very very slow as I try.

Comment: @yode what is the order of magnitude of length of `bigList` and a `veryBigList`?

Comment: `bigList` is $10^6$.`veryBigList` is $10^7$ or more

Answer (score 2):

**This may be the fastest way in my analysis so far and may compete with `Fold` or perhaps perform better**

```
Module[{m = Range@10},
SetAttributes[func, HoldFirst];
func[x_, {}] := x; 
func[x_, y_] := (x[[y[[1, 2]] ]] = BitSet[x[[y[[1, 2]]]], y[[1, 1]]];
func[x, Rest@y]);

func[m, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4, 10}}] // AbsoluteTiming
]

(* {0.0000401216, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 26}} *)
```

**other attempts**

```
Module[{list = Range@10, i = 0, pos, ind,
indices = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4, 10}}},
Nest[(pos = indices[[++i, 2]];
ind = indices[[i, 1]];
ReplacePart[#, pos -> BitSet[#[[pos]], ind]]) &, list, 
Length@indices]]// AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0000979715, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 26}} *)
```

this can be made faster using:

```
Module[{list = Range@10, i = 0, pos, ind,
indices = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4, 10}}},
Nest[(pos = indices[[++i, 2]];
ind = indices[[i, 1]];
list[[pos]] = BitSet[list[[pos]], ind];
list) &, list, Length@indices]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0000639147, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 26}} *)
```

with `Do` we can get slightly better:

```
Module[{list = Range@10, pos, ind, 
indices = {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4, 10}}},
Do[(pos = i[[2]];
 ind = i[[1]];
 list[[pos]] = BitSet[list[[pos]], ind]);,
{i, indices}];list] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0000513184, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 26}} *)
```

However, the method suggested by Kuba is still the fastest

```
Fold[Function[{data, spec}, 
MapAt[BitSet[#, spec[[1]]] &, data, #2] & @@ spec], 
Range@10, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 7}, {2, 9}, {4,10}}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0000438539, {1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 26}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[func_, lst_] :=  Module[{funcs = func[1, #] & @@@ #, pos = #2 & @@@ #}, 
    ReplacePart[lst, Thread[pos -> MapThread[# @ #2 &, {funcs, lst[[pos]]}]]]] &;

f1[f, {a, b, c, d}]@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> `{a, f[1, 1][b], c, f[1, 3][d]}`

or

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[func_, lst_] := Module[{funcs = func[1, #] & @@@ #, pos = #2 & @@@ #, l2 = lst}, 
    l2[[pos]] = MapThread[#@#2 &, {funcs, lst[[pos]]}]; l2] &;

f2[f, {a, b, c, d}]@{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

> `{a, f[1, 1][b], c, f[1, 3][d]}`